# How to import psycopg2 when installed - Windows

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2

Can somebody please help me install this psycopg2 which I dont even know what it is. I have no python knowledge, I need this to run a code to connect to read data from txt to postgres.

Problem is, I have installed psycopg2 from exe and but when I run import psycopg2 in python shell I get an error:

```
import psycopg2
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       import psycopg2 ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

the pip install in windows doesn't seem to work well and ends up with the error you have mentioned. You can try the binaries provided in [StickPeople website](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/). These binaries install without problem and will allow you to access psycopg2. Please check the version of python you have installed with the version of the psycopg2 version. If they  don't match up, it'll result in such errors. Even the architecture x86 or x64 matters.
`C:\> easy_install psycopg2-2.6.1.win32-py2.7-pg9.4.4-release.exe`, 
you can try this if the binary fails.

Comment: U did that too and it gave me error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat... I just read somewhere that I could install Spyder and run it from there and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i think Psycopg2 is not installed.
please install psycopg2 using pip 
like:
pip install psycopg2
once done with this you can import

Comment: I have installed it using pip and it would still not import... I had to install anaconda and install it from there..Now it works..